# How Java ArrayList works internally

Tags: java, arraylist

In below code I passed list (defined in main) to remove_dup method and it updated actual arraylist (list).As Java is pass by value then why list got updated by remove_dup method.

Then I created another list2 using list but if I add a element in list2 its not getting added to list.

Why one is updating main list and other approach not ?

```
        public class ArrayListTest {

            public static void remove_dups(ArrayList<String> list, int n) {

                Set<String> unqList = new TreeSet<String>(list);
                list.clear();
                list.addAll(unqList);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                list.add("one");
                list.add("two");
                list.add("two");

                remove_dups(list);
        //As Java is pass by value then why its printing unique values here?
  //expected output---- One two two but its printing one two
                for (String string : list) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                }

                ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(list);

                list2.add("three");

                for (String string : list2) {
                    System.out.println("list 2-" + string);
                }

    //I was expecting "three to be printed with list" 
                for (String string : list) {
                    System.out.println("list 1-" + string);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can not recreate your problem; when testing list2 contains "three" as expected. Your code won't compile though as the variable n is undefined.

Comment: What do you think `new ArrayList<String>(list);` does?

Comment: Did you expect the first list to also contain "three"?

Comment: Once the second argument to `remove_dups` is removed your code runs fine and outputs the expected result so this question should be closed.

Comment: When you pass `list` to `remove_dups`, you're passing it a reference to the original object, this allows `remove_dups` to modify the contents.  When call `new ArrayList<String>(list)`, it makes a new `List` with the contents of `list`, but modifying `list2` won't change `list` as there is no longer a connection between the two, they are two different instances of `List`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think you understood what I am trying to ask here. But Java is pass by value.

Comment: *”Java is always pass-by-value. Unfortunately, when we pass the value of an object, we are passing the reference to it. This is confusing to beginners.”* and welcome to a world of confusion 

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer . Its clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an `ArrayList` to a function it passes a pointer back to the original list. That means any updates in the method will be updating your original `ArrayList` because they are the same thing.

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(list);
```

That makes a copy of list and saves it into `list2`. list and `list2` are completely separate `ArrayList`'s.

Comment: "If you pass an ArrayList to a function it passes by reference..." -- No, everything in Java is [pass by value](http://www.javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: The pointer to the ArrayList is passed by value to the method. The pointer points back to the memory space of the ArrayList. A copy of the entire ArrayList is not passed by value.

Comment: "A copy of the entire ArrayList is not passed by value." - I did not say it was.  Read the linked article.  There is a difference between passing an object reference by value, and passing by reference.

Comment: @azurefrog the link is helpful.Thanks